# Is a n multi-step proof rigorous and verification of one.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces, vectors

I have been working through Linear Algebra Done Right by Axler. I came upon this problem and was wondering if my answer was correct.

If $U_1,...,U_n$ are finite-dimensional subspace of a vector space V. Then prove that $U_1+...+U_n$ is finite-dimensional and $dim(U_1+...+U_n)\leq dimU_1+...+dimU_n$.

1. Step 1

   Since $U_1,U_2$ are finite dimensional there exists a basis $a_1,...,a_n$, $b_1,...,b_m$ for each subspace respectively. Adjoin these two lists and it becomes apparent that the newly created list,B, spans $U_1+U_2$ and hence the vector space $U_1+U_2$ is finite-dimensional. Due to the dimension of a sum theorem it then follows that $dim(U_1+U_2)\leq dimU_1+dimU_2$. Let $U_1+U_2=U_1'$.
2. Step J

Since $U_1+...+U_j=U_{j-1}',U_{j+1}$ are finite dimensional following the same logic as step 1 we can conclude that $U_{j-1}'+U_{j+1}$ is finite dimensional. Thus by the dimension of a sum theorm it follows that $dim(U_1+...+U_j+U_{j+1})\leq dimU_1+...+dimU_j+dimU_{j+1}$.

Continuing this process n-1 times it follows that the original statement is true.

---

I apologize if there are any trivial errors. Also I was wondering how rigorous a multi-step proof of this sort is considered in the mathematical community. It appears logically sound to me but not logically watertight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're getting at the notion of [mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).

Loosely, for each $n\in \Bbb N$ we have a statement $P(n)$ saying

> If $U_1,\dotsc,U_n$ are finite-dimensional subspaces of a vector space $V$, then $U_1+\dotsb+U_n$ is finite-dimensional and $\dim(U_1+\dotsb+U_n)\leq \dim U_1+\dotsb+\dim U_n$.

Mathematical induction states that to prove that $P(n)$ is true for *every* $n\in\Bbb N$ it suffices to show that

1. $P(1)$ is true (this is often called the *base case*)
2. if $P(n)$ is true for some $n\in\Bbb N$, then $P(n+1)$ is true (this is often called the *inductive step*)

Notice that your "proof" closely resembles mathematical induction.

If I was writing a proof of this statement, it would look something like this:

*Proof.* Induct on $n$.

The base case $n=2$ is the [dimension theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dimension_of_Sum_and_Intersection_of_Vector_Spaces).

Now, suppose inductively that 
$$
\dim(U_1+\dotsb+U_n)\leq\dim U_1+\dotsb+\dim U_n
$$
for any $U_1,\dotsc,U_n$ finite-dimensional subspaces of $V$. Then let $U_1,\dotsc,U_{n+1}$ be finite-dimensional subspaces of $V$. It follows that
\begin{align*}
\dim(U_1+\dotsb+U_n+U_{n+1})
&\leq \dim(U_1+\dotsb+U_n)+\dim U_{n+1} \\
&\leq \dim U_1+\dotsb+\dim U_n
\end{align*}
where the first inequality follows from the [dimension theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dimension_of_Sum_and_Intersection_of_Vector_Spaces) and the second inequality follows from the inductive hypothesis. $\Box$

Of course, I've used the dimension theorem as a lemma. If this lemma was unavailable, then you would include it as part of the proof (which you've done in your "Step 1").

Comment: Thank you very much for some reason I thought the multi-step approach was somehow different then mathematical induction. I realize now that it is not.